# Creating Highcharts multiple series with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, highcharts

I've been trying to create multiple series for a Highchart graph for days to no avail. I've tried numerous examples but I can't form the necessary json_encodeed needed. Any help would be great, obviously my PHP skills are lacking. If I'm going about this the wrong way, please feel free to advise.

This is what I'd like to end up with:

```
series: [{
                name: 'Temperature',
                data: [
                    [Date.UTC(1970,  9, 27), 0   ],
                    [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 10), 0.6 ],
                    [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 18), 0.7 ],
                    [Date.UTC(1970, 11,  2), 0.8 ]
                      ]
            }, {
                name: 'Salinity',
                data: [
                    [Date.UTC(1970,  9, 18), 0   ],
                    [Date.UTC(1970,  9, 26), 0.2 ]

                ]
            }, {
                name: 'Disolved Oxygen',
                data: [
                    [Date.UTC(1970,  9,  9), 0   ],
                    [Date.UTC(1970,  9, 14), 0.15],
                      ]
```

Below is my latest PHP attempt from [this post](http://blueflame-software.com/blog/how-to-load-mysql-results-to-highcharts-using-json/). I'm not sure how to implement with 2 fields.

```
$chart1 = pg_query($connection, "SELECT sample_date, a FROM monitor_nutrient WHERE station_num_id = 1 ORDER BY sample_date ASC");
$row_a = array();
$row_a['name'] = 'Temperature';
while ($ra = pg_fetch_array($chart1)) {
    $row_a['data'][] = $ra['a'];
}

$chart1 = pg_query($connection, "SELECT sample_date, b FROM monitor_nutrient WHERE station_num_id = 1 ORDER BY sample_date ASC");
$row_b = array();
$row_b['name'] = 'Salinity';
while ($rb = pg_fetch_array($chart1)) {
    $row_b['data'][] = $rb['b'];
}

$chart1 = pg_query($connection, "SELECT sample_date, c FROM monitor_nutrient WHERE station_num_id = 1 ORDER BY sample_date ASC");
$row_c = array();
$row_c['name'] = 'Dissolved Oxygen';
while ($rc = pg_fetch_array($chart1)) {
    $row_c['data'][] = $rc['c'];
}

$result = array();
array_push($result, $row_a);
array_push($result, $row_b);
array_push($result, $row_c);

print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Comment: what does the pasted code generate? why is it wrong? because it only has one field per data row? what should the other field be?

Comment: it produces this: data: [19.2, 18.4, 6.4, 1.1, 4.6, 10.3, 11.7, 18.5, 11.3, 5.2, 4.1, 2.6, 3.8, 11.7, 12.2, 17.9, 25.7, 21.76,…], I'd like to precede the data with 'sample_date'   like this [Date.UTC(1970,  9, 27), 0   ],
[Date.UTC(1970, 10, 10), 0.6 ] but I don't know how to do that

Comment: what about using `$row_c['data'][] = array($rc['sample_date'], $rc['c']);` instead of `$row_c['data'][] = $rc['c'];`?

Comment: that worked perfectly, thanks so much. No way I would have figured that out on my own. Any suggestions on how to handle the date? With PHP server side or javascript on client side?

Comment: what format is the date in like this? JSON doesn't support dates, so you have to do some client-side stuff. I'd recommend just transmitting the UNIX time and building a date object on the client-side using `new Date(...)`

Comment: not sure what format, but I've tried your suggestion with some success a few days ago. Hope I can create it again

Comment: probably it already is already in that format. If it is a giant number, it is.

Comment: So it works or not? Have you modified JSON ?

Comment: It almost works, having problems with dates.                      $date = str_replace("-",",",$rb['sample_date']); creates ["2012,06,12",20.38], what I need is: [Date.UTC(2012, 06, 12), 20.38],    not sure how to do it client or server side. please help!!!

Comment: You need to parse your json and prepare in output correct form like Date.UTC. In the loop in javascript, you can use slice() function, and then push to Date.utc() correct values.